# Angular4/5 multiple router modules as child and one parent router module

Tags: angular, angular-router

How i can have multiple router module like i have core and main as to module in angular and they will have different separate routing module and i want to import those two routing module in our app.routing.ts/app.module.ts as a parent routing module. Is there is any solution to it ?

Comment: yes. have you read the [documentation \ official tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/router) ?

Comment: Thanks , I have gone through it

Comment: well then you probably read that `RouterModule.forChild(heroesRoutes)` describes exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I have to modify my question i think that is not about child it about a multiple router module

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you [read the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router).
you can spread your application features to modules. each module should have its own routes with it.

so say we're talking about eagerly loaded modules,
`app.module.ts` will import the base routing module (the parent, core routes), and each feature module, will import its own related routes.

`app.module.ts` will then import all the feature modules. along with their routes.

the **only difference** between core routes and the feature routes is exporting the routes using `.forChild(routes)` in the feature routes, and `.forRoot(routes)` for the core routes.

you can have as many `.forChild()` imports as you'd like, but you shuold use only one `.forRoot()` preferably in the core module.

**App.Module.ts** (does not contain routes in it, only imports other route modules)

```
// import { ... } from '...';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppFeatureRoutingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**App-routing.Module.ts** (core routes)

```
// import { ...} from '...';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', children: [
        { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'enter', component: EnterComponent }
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**App-feature-routing.Module.ts** (feature routes)

```
  // import { ...} from '...';

    const featureRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: 'myFeatureIndex', component: FeatureIndexComponent }
    ];

    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forChild(featureRoutes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppFeatureRoutingModule { }
```

So App.Module imports both core routes, and every feature route, separately.
you can have as many feature routes as you wish. behind the scenes Angular will end up chaining all them `.forChild()` routes and `forRoot()` routes to one big route and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  {
    path:'parent-path',
    children: [
      {
        path:'first-child-path',
        loadChildren: () => import('../app/modules/your-first-child.routing').then(m => m.FirstChildRoutingModule),
        canActivate: [YourGuard]
      },
      {
        path:'second-child-path',
        loadChildren: () => import('../app/modules/second-child.module').then(m => m.SecondChildOrderModule),
        canActivate: [SecondGuard]
      },
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).